# Why is there a difference in asterisk location in this case, but not others?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm creating a vector of pointers member of class Location, within class Location, so:

```
class Location //(simplified to prevent long code)
{
private:
std::string name, description;
int id;
std::vector<Item> items;

public:
Location();
~Location();

std::vector<Location*> nextLocations; //vector of pointers
};
```

Why does my code compile with

```
std::vector<Location*> nextLocations;
```

but not with

```
std::vector<Location> *nextLocations;
```

What's the difference? I thought

```
int* i;
```

and

```
int *i;
```

were the same? Isn't the vector still a vector of Location pointers either way? My member function in Location class, named addLoc(), does not work unless the parameter takes in the address to a location, and then does a push_back on nextLocations. But when I push_back, why do I have to use

```
nextLocations.push_back(&location);
```

and not

```
nextLocations->push_back(&location);
```

isn't each element of nextLocations supposed to be a pointer?

Comment: Because they mean different things, `std::vector<Location*> nextLocations;` this is a vector of pointers to Location objects, `std::vector<Location> *nextLocations;` this is a pointer to a vector of Location objects. `int *i` and `int* i` is the same because it's just spaces, this is not so in the vector case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `int* i;` ans `int *i;` are the same thing. However, for example, something outside parenthesis (or something equivalent) is not the same. So,

```
myfunc(i) + 7;
```

is not the same as

```
myfunc(i + 7);
```

Think of `<>` like parenthesis. Thus:

```
std::vector<Location *> nextLocations;
```

is not the same as:

```
std::vector<Location> *nextLocations;
```

If you're confused what the difference is, the first is a vector of Location pointers. The second is a pointer to a vector of Locations, which, again, isn't the same. Make sure you choose the right one :